# Swift keeps embedding its 5.0 standard library in my project

Tags: ios, swift, dynamic-library

I've checked that all of the frameworks in my app, as well as the main binary, have the same swiftversion (1100.2.255, which means Swift 5.1). However, I see that Xcode is still embedding standard library dylibs (all for Swift 5.0). In my build settings, I have "always embed Swift standard libraries" set to false for all projects. How can I stop Xcode from embedding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deployment target must be iOS 12.2 or higher